# Replace initial commit with another one

Tags: git

I made the first initial commit into remote repository (to origin develop branch), which is completely empty, but after that I restructured the files and folders in my workspace. In order to undo the first commit and replace it with next one I used this command:

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

Then I staged my files, commited and pushed them with this command:

```
git push origin develop -f
```

But I received this:

```
error: src refspec develop does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to ...
```

I tried to push without using force, but got this:

```
To ssh ...
! [rejected]        feature/<branch_name> -> feature/<branch_name> (non-fast-forward)
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I hit `git pull origin develop` but received:

```
* branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Now I am stuck. I am not sure what is happening. I can neither pull nor push. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: `git rebase --interactive --root`.

Comment: look into: git push --force

Comment: thank you Eyal D, that worked for me